# ElasticSearch: Unable to delete index using API, Manual deletion?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We have several indices that we cannot delete by calling the ElasticSearch API

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/logstash-2014.01.20"

{"error":"IndexMissingException[[logstash-2014.01.20] missing]","status":404}
```

How can these be safely removed from our Cluster?  Can these be deleted manually from /nodes/0/indices?

Answer (score 2):

`IndexMissingException` is only thrown when there is no such an index with this name. Either your index is already deleted, or you did not provide the correct name.

Comment: Looks like indexes were left before we had curator in place.  They have the correct name, they are taking up a couple hundred gigs of space across the cluster in the data directories.  Can these file be removed safely?

Comment: Yes, you can delete this index from files.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Chasmo, your index is missing or has already been deleted. If don't want to follow the manual process of deleting indices on regular basic (as logstash creates index on daily basis), there is a command line utility provided by ElasticSearch named `curator`. It is very useful in deleting, closing, and optimizing indices.

Here is a link `https://github.com/elasticsearch/curator/wiki`. Using this utility (written in pearl) you can set a cron job for auto deleting indices on regular basis.